# Disable mouse wheel zooming and user-rotation on 3D embedded model in wordpress website

Tags: html, mousewheel, 3d-model

I have an embedded 3D model on my wordpress website which I created, now hosted online by creators3d.

I want to alter the code somehow so you wouldn't be able to zoom in with the mouse or click&rotate as a visitor. I want to do this because it's in the header of the page and you can't really scroll the page because the cursor is stuck on the model.

Here is the current code:

```
<div class="creators-embed-wrapper">

  <iframe width="640" height="480" src="https://v.creators3d.com/index.html?load=%2Fviews%2Fproduction%2Fitem%2F20230821%2F3803837859589964%2F3803837859589964.glb&autorotate=true&json-data=1692612413875&decrypt=1&tv=147" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; vr" mozallowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" style="border: none"></iframe>

</div>
```

Is there a way to solve this?

I tried involving commands such as style="pointer-events:none" but maybe I am not incorporating them correctly.

Comment: "Here is the current code:"  Nope. Please add it.

Comment: <div class="creators-embed-wrapper">

  <iframe width="640" height="480" src="https://v.creators3d.com/index.html?load=%2Fviews%2Fproduction%2Fitem%2F20230821%2F3803837859589964%2F3803837859589964.glb&autorotate=true&json-data=1692612413875&decrypt=1&tv=147" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; vr" mozallowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" style="border: none"></iframe>

</div>

It's also on the question, but apparently it's not showing :(

Comment: Ok so it appears that you just forgot to add code formatting. I tried to fix it, please edit the question if something's off.

Comment: Yes, now it showing correctly. Thanks!